# How do I highlight #-comments in UPF files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim

I have a file with the extension `*.upf` in which the `#` is not highlighted. I use `#` for comments. `:syntax on` also doesn't seem to work.

The issue here is I have a file (`*.upf`) which is generated by design compiler which has `##` being highlighted but if I make a manual file (`*.upf`) I don't see it highlighted.

Comment: In the file that gets highlighted, check the output of `:set syntax? filetype?` If this returns something, than vim detected it as a type to highlight. Than you set need to use `:set ft=<return_value_from_previous_command>`. If it didn't detect it, you may try some generic ones, like `:set ft=conf`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't have anything related to `.upf` file extension out of the box.

No syntax files, no filetypes. You can check it by navigating to `:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax` or/and by checking filetype detection rules in `:e $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`.

So the question is how in the first place you have `##` highlighted in `.upf` file generated by some program. Did you install some third-party ftplugin?

If you want to add custom syntax highlighing...

### add to vimrc

```
augroup UPF | au!
    au BufRead,BufNew *.upf set filetype=upf
augroup END
```

### create/add to ~/.vim/syntax/upf.vim

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

syn match upfComment "^\s*#\s.*$" contains=@Spell

hi def link upfComment Comment

let b:current_syntax = "upf"

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
```

Comment: Likely the # triggered the conf filetype